# cannot enable webgl for chromium in virtualbox

Tags: google-chrome, webgl, virtualbox, chromium

I'm trying to run webgl in chromium browser in virtualbox on Ubuntu 14.04.

First I set in **chrome://settings** hardware acceleration when available to checked, 
then in **chrome://flags** I enabled everything about webgl, 
but in **chrome://gpu** I still have status **WebGL: Unavailable**.
In virtualbox setting I checked 3D acceleration, not 2D acceleration.

Please, don't you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: check also 2D acceleration ;)

Comment: 2D acceleration is for windows guest only

Comment: Need to install Guest Additions. And add equal or more than 26 Mb of video RAM.
And then it's possible to add `--use-gl=egl` to Chromium command line. 
But this produces strange drawing artifacts in my case (kiosk mode and virtual keyboard), so I cannot recommend this solution.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried enable the flag of ＂Override software rendering list＂ in chrome://flags, or append command line switch "--ignore-gpu-blacklist"?